# How to create chart in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, charts, windows-phone

I am using the chart in my windows phone 8 application. As I am using [amchart quick chart](https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts) but it doesn't provide full documentation so I am not able to customize my Pie Chart according to data. I am looking out for some customized charts. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. As I have also googled for [Silverlight 5 Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435) but can anyone please tell is it ok to use this toolkit.

Does Windows Phone have any inbuild feature to support charts and graphs?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following as well,

[sparrowtoolkit.](http://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/) which supports WP8.

Here are few other Chart Documentation Links

[How to Create Charts Graphs in Your Windows Phone Application](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/wp7/article.php/c20199/How-to-Create-Charts--Graphs-in-Your-Windows-Phone-Application.htm)